# Can I do "on device testing" from europe

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

I am trying to test my capsule from my device.
steps taken to test it:

- Privately published capsule on Bixby studio (accepted)
- Linked Samsung account to Bixby team
- Enabled developer options on phone (Samsung galaxy 9)
- Enabled On device testing + entered revision ID as it appears on Bixby Studio
- Entered command "test" to which my capsule should respond

When "test" has been entered Bixby responds with "I couldn't understand that. Here are some Capsules your can try." Unfortunately, it does NOT show me capsules I can try neither given me the expected response.

Important note (maybe): I live and try to test in an European country where the Bixby marketplace is not available yet. VPN to US does not help either.

Can I still test my capsule on my phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do on-device testing from Europe, you need to provision Bixby in the US for the phone you want to do testing on.

1. Go to Settings -> Apps -> Bixby Voice -> Storage Clear Data
2. Same as(1) but for Bixby Service Plug in a US-based SIM card
3. If you don't have a US-based SIM card, you can pull the SIM out and
   connect device via VPN to a US-based server.
4. Start Bixby to start new provisioning process

Answer (score 0):

It should be ok to do on-device testing.

Make sure you only sync one capsule during submission.

There is an easy way to test: you can load the revision number using IDE simulator's revision override feature. See attachment. 
[image]

Comment: Forgot to mention that it's working in the bixby developer simulator with the override. Just not on my phone. (with the same Revision ID)

Comment: is there only one capsule in the revision id, or multiple? You may want to add the screenshot of your revision override from IDE