# Can sample capsule be used for on-device testing on Bixby?

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

I'm currently facing some issues with on-device testing for my capsule, as listed here, [On device testing didn't response (private submission)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60947674/on-device-testing-didnt-response-private-submission)
So I worked on the NL training, and tried again, but no luck. Then, I've had an idea to try on-device testing for the sample capsule. https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/sample-capsules/samples.

> Because you cannot submit a capsule with the example namespace, in order to test a sample capsule on a device, you must change the id in the capsule.bxb file from example to your organization's before making a private submission.

I follow the instruction above and try out audio capsule [image]

Yet the capsule is still not responding with the command for that capsule training. So i am kind of curious, whether the sample capsule is working for on-device testing, or my phone is not compatible for the on-device testing. Is there any clearer information on how to load the capsule other from here https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/testing.on-device. And compatible device information for on-device testing.

[Edit] Found this [Can I do "on device testing" from europe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58854343/can-i-do-on-device-testing-from-europe). I am from South-East Asia, so I couldn't test capsule with target en-US?

Answer (score 0):

The other post you linked ([Can I do "on device testing" from europe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58854343/can-i-do-on-device-testing-from-europe)) is correct. Since you are located in a region that does not currently have Bixby Marketplace, you would need to either 1) obtain a device from a supported region such as the US or 2) use the Simulator to test.

Comment: I been able to run the on-device test, when i change my capsule target from en-US to en. Looks like my device is not targeted on en-US, the locale and market is affect the testing somehow.